# CakePHP - saving HABTM fails

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, cakephp-2.x

I have tables that looks like this. Basically WarehousePlace can have many ItemType in it and ItemType can be used by many WarehousePlace. But when I try to save I get an database error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'WarehousePlacesItemType.item_type_id' in 'field list'

SQL Query: SELECT `WarehousePlacesItemType`.`item_type_id` FROM `modules`.`warehouse_places_item_types` AS `WarehousePlacesItemType` WHERE `WarehousePlacesItemType`.`warehouse_place_id` = '22'
```

But everything is done by conventions and also debugged data is like it should be and I do not see what is wrong.

WarehousesController

```
public function add() {
        $this->load();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $data = array(
                'WarehousePlace' => array(
                    'name' => $this->request->data['WarehousePlace']['name'],
                ),
                'ItemType' => array(
                    'ItemType' => $this->request->data['ItemType']['ItemType']
                )
            );
            $this->WarehousePlace->create();

            if ($this->WarehousePlace->saveAll($data, array('validate' => 'first', 'deep' => true))) {
//success
            }
            if ($this->WarehousePlace->validationErrors) {
                //validation
            } else {
                //error
            }
        }
    }
```

tables:

```
warehouse_places_item_types(warehouse_places_id,item_types_id) -> no primary key since CakePHP 2,

warehouse_places(id, name),

item_types(id, name)
```

Models:

ItemType

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'WarehousePlace' => array(
        'className' => 'WarehousePlace',
        'joinTable' => 'warehouse_places_item_types',
        'foreignKey' => 'item_type_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'warehouse_place_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
    )
);
```

WarehousePlace

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'ItemType' => array(
        'className' => 'ItemType',
        'joinTable' => 'warehouse_places_item_types',
        'foreignKey' => 'warehouse_place_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'item_type_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
    )
);
```

Comment: You are referencing `item_type_id` all over, but the table schema you've provided says it's `item_types_id`. Likewise for `warehouse_place_id` and `warehouse_places_id`.

Comment: This solved it.

Comment: CakePHP baked it like that, but I should know better.